# Translation of the phrase: 生きる水 in context

Tags: translation, words, song-lyrics, puns

So I was translating this song ([full lyrics](https://www5.atwiki.jp/hmiku/pages/25196.html), [song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0dyAlYhicXk), line at 3:26) and I ran across this line which I'm very confused about.

> 無駄な事は聞かないよ　それが君の生きる水なら。
> I don't listen to/I don't ask useless things. If that's your living water.

The second part is what I'm confused about. "Living water" is a poetry anthology by 高塚かず子, but I'm not sure if that's being referred to here, though it is the most common usage I found of the phrase when I ran it through google. I'm wondering if it's a pun, especially considering there is a part in the song that mirrors it: 生き死体の君が言うんなら (If you, the living corpse, says so). I'm wondering if these are connected in meaning in some way, though I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 6):

This song is full of puns. After looking at the line for a few seconds, I thought this was probably a comical reference to 生きる道 ("way of life"), which is a [recurring](https://www.uta-net.com/user/index_search/search2.html?frm=ichiran&kw=%E7%94%9F%E3%81%8D%E3%82%8B%E9%81%93) phrase used in poems and lyrics. It's [on jisho](http://jisho.org/word/%E7%94%9F%E3%81%8D%E3%82%8B%E9%81%93), too. There is a famous song titled [これが私の生きる道](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%93%E3%82%8C%E3%81%8C%E7%A7%81%E3%81%AE%E7%94%9F%E3%81%8D%E3%82%8B%E9%81%93). 道 was replaced by 水 because "road" does not make much sense in water. So it's "water you live in" rather than "living water". (This may not be the type of question that has a single correct answer. This is just how *I* felt about the line.)